# How to prove basic properties that follow from the axioms of a field?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory

I am recently learning about fields and frequently get stuck whole trying to prove some properties that drop out of the axioms. I'll give an example to try and see how too go about doing it.

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{F}$ some field. Then prove $(-m)n=-(mn)=-mn$. Now I know $(-m)$ is the unique element of the field such that $(-m)+m=0$ and $-mn$ is the unique element of the field such that $(-mn)+mn=0$

I have so far done $(-m)n=(-m1)n=(-1\cdot(mn))=-1\cdot (mn)$ but I don't know how to just write this is $=-(mn).$

Comment: How did you get $(-m1)n=-1\cdot(mn)$?

Comment: Associativity of multiplication in the ring. Is that step wrong?

Comment: In general, when you want to proof $x=-y$, you always should look at $x+y$ and show that it is zero. In those basic consequences from the axioms, this is always the right choice to find a proof.

Comment: What specific elements are you applying associativity to?  I don't see a "$-1$" anywhere on the left-hand side.  (The step is correct, but it needs more justification, and the method of justification will probably be helpful for the last step too.)

Comment: So we want to start with $(-m)n+(-mn)$ and try to show it's zero?

Comment: Use distributivity.

Comment: Now, you want to look at $(-m)n+mn$ of course, since you want to proof $(-m)n=-(mn)$

Comment: Ah okay yes I see the method now but I don't see how I would go about showing $(-m)n+mn=0$ would I factor out and $n$ and say it's equal to $n((-m)+m)=m0=0$ so it is the unique inverse element we want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the correct proof, provided you have already shown that $n \cdot 0=0$ for any $n$.

Comment: Yeah I have thank you sir. I think I just need to keep practising more and more to get the experience!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$(−1)\cdot(mn) + mn = (−1)\cdot(mn) + 1\cdot mn = ((-1) +1)mn = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

From $m+(-m)=0$ ( definition of the opposite element), by distributivity we have:
$$
(m+(-m))\times n=0 \times n \quad \iff \quad m\times n+(-m)\times n=0\times n
$$

since $0 \times n=0 \quad \forall n$, this is:

$$
 m\times n+(-m)\times n=0
$$

and, by definition and unicity of the opposite this means that
$$
-(mn)=(-m)n
$$

You can do the same for $m\times (-n)$.